# Dart: A question from a newcomer: Functions

Tags: function, dart, return

*Thank you very much in advance!
How to change the output sequence in this code?
So that 'PRINT' is output immediately after 'RETURN ANSWER'.
So that it becomes:*

An example of what is needed:

```
What is dog:
answer.
The dog is: answer.
What is flower:
answer.
The flower is: answer.
```

[image]

My current code:

```
void main() {
  String? dog = prompt('What is a dog:');
  String? flower = prompt('What is a flower:');
  print('The dog is: ${dog}');
  print('The flower is: ${flowers}');
}

String? prompt(String promtpText) {
  print('${promtpText}');
  String? answer = stdin.readLineSync();
  return answer;
}
```

Comment: Please add an text example of how you want the output of the application should be exactly. The current explanation is not precise enough.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  String? dog = prompt('What is a dog:');
  print('The dog is: $dog');

  String? flower = prompt('What is a flower:');
  print('The flower is: $flower');
}

String? prompt(String promtpText) {
  print('$promtpText ');
  String? answer = stdin.readLineSync();
  return answer;
}
```

Output:

```
What is a dog: 
shepherd
The dog is: shepherd
What is a flower: 
rose
The flower is: rose
```

### With delay

If you want to make it so the application does not write lines as fast as possible, you can insert delays by doing the following:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  String? dog = prompt('What is a dog:');
  print('The dog is: $dog');

  // Wait two seconds to create the illusion of complicated application :)
  await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

  String? flower = prompt('What is a flower:');
  print('The flower is: $flower');
}

String? prompt(String promtpText) {
  print('$promtpText ');
  String? answer = stdin.readLineSync();
  return answer;
}
```

### With additional enter key between questions

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  String? dog = prompt('What is a dog:');
  print('The dog is: $dog');

  prompt('Click enter for next question...');

  String? flower = prompt('What is a flower:');
  print('The flower is: $flower');
}

String? prompt(String promtpText) {
  print('$promtpText ');
  String? answer = stdin.readLineSync();
  return answer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. But I meant how to change the code sequence.
Now:
What is a dog? ==> Answer ==> What is a flower? ==> Answer== > Print Print.

Need:

What is a dog?== > Answer ==> Print== > What is a flower?== >Answer ==> Print

I apologize if this is not the correct question.

Comment: Ah sorry. Why not just move the lines so you have the `print` right after the call of prompt? Updated my answer with what I mean. I hope this is what you are asking for. :)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help either. In this case. 'Answer' and 'What is flower:' displayed at the same time.

Comment: What should happen before the next question are being asked? Can you please show an example of how the flow of this application are suppose to be? Your previous attempt at doing so are really unclear since my current attempted solution does exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Updated my answer again. This time it prints exactly the same output as showed in the screenshot provided in the question.

Comment: Yes, but the lines
'The dog is shepherd' and 'What is a flower' are displayed at the same time. Need line by line.

Comment: @AmirHokage So there should be some kind of delay between this two lines being printed? How long delay?

Comment: Any delay would help me. Or an additional press of the "enter'' key.

Comment: @AmirHokage Updated answer again... If this is still not correct I am going to give up and remove my answer. You are really pushing it when it comes to come up with new requirements which never was part of the question in the first place...

Comment: I agree with you, I have as a newcomer, it just lacks knowledge. To teach and study again. Thank you for your time!